# Negative binomial with a rational power?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I didn't quite understand the expansion of, for instance $1 \over (1-x)^\alpha$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$, for instance for $\alpha = {1\over 2}$ using the binomial coefficients. I know that for $\alpha \in \mathbb N$, ${1 \over (1-x)^\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^∞ {n+\alpha-1 \choose \alpha-1}x^n$, but I don't know how to apply it when $\alpha$ isn't whole.

Thanks in advance for any explanation!

Comment: Have you tried reading say [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) on topic? If so, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Yes I did. But it doesn't mention the case where the power isn't whole, and if it did then I didn't really understand it.

Comment: Use http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem or http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Binomial_Theorem#Generalizations

Comment: It is my understandind that the OP is asking for the definition of $\alpha \choose k$ when $\alpha \not \in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the definition of $\displaystyle {m\choose k}\color{grey}{=\frac{m!}{(m-k!)k!}}$.

Now note that $\dfrac{m!}{(m-k!)k!}=\dfrac{m\cdot (m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)\cdot(m-k)!}{(m-k)!k!}=\dfrac{m\cdot (m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)}{k!}$.

Consider $\dfrac{m\cdot (m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)}{k!}$. What do you need $m$ to be for it to make sense?

Comment: What does a rational factorial even mean? If we put n=1/2, what do we even get? I don't really understand :s

Comment: @ohad In your question this $${1 \over (1-x)^\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^∞ {n+\alpha-1 \choose \alpha-1}x^n$$ is wrong. The coefficient should  be $(-1)^n{\alpha \choose n}$. Having said this, do you now understand?

Comment: Sorry my friend, I forgot to accept! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental formula is
$$
  (1+X)^\alpha = \sum_{k\geq0} \binom\alpha kX^k,
$$
valid as an identity of formal power series in$~X$ for all $\alpha$,
where by definition
$$
 \binom\alpha k=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\ldots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}.
$$
The latter formula allows "negating the upper index":
$$
  (-1)^k\binom{-\alpha}k=\binom{\alpha+k-1}k
$$
which is also valid for arbitrary$~\alpha$. This then allows the initial formula to be reformulated as
$$
\frac1{(1-X)^\alpha}=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k\binom{-\alpha}kX^k
=\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{\alpha+k-1}kX^k.
$$
So that is the correct formula, not the one given in the question.

What you appear to have done is apply symmetry: $\binom{\alpha+k-1}k=\binom{\alpha+k-1}{\alpha-1}$. But that is *only* valid when the upper index is a nonnegative integer, which requires (if it is to hold for all $k\geq0$) that $\alpha$ be a positive *integer*. So you cannot apply it when $\alpha=\frac12$, as you did (indeed the resulting binomial coefficient is not even defined by the above definition).